# Scam: Sent ETH to HEX Contract - Where is it?

Tags: security

I sent ETH to the HEX contract, waited for 24 hours to transform and was ready to click "exit" at the end but it just disappeared?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the Ethereum Stack Exchange!

HEX is a scam.  It doesn't look like you will get anything.

Example https://twitter.com/sassal0x/status/1256578671218790400

Sorry for your loss.  Be careful out there.

Feel free to post on Twitter or Reddit to get help avoiding scams.